# paypal IPN btn_id for subscription button

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am having an issue with paypal subscription buttons. I have followed paypal doc and have a working paypal button. I'm able to receive the IPN.

The problem is that when I try to check the button ID receive in the IPN, it doesn't match any of my button IDs:

- In the HTML form, I send a 13-digit ID composed of numbers and capital letters (the one given by my paypal account).
- In the field `btn_id` of the IPN, I receive a 8-digit ID (numbers only)

I can't find anything in the doc about this 2nd kind of IDs, and so I can't figure out the difference between different subscriptions I receive.

Can anyone explain me about this `btn_id` field?

Comment: Show us what you've done. Mere description is inadequate.

Comment: There's not much to show. I copy-paste the HTML code from my paypal account and I the `btn_id` in the IPN is not the one taht is sent.

Comment: in HTML: `<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="<13-digit numbers+capital letters>">`
in IPN: btn_id = <8-digit numbers>